# Evaluating percentages to pixels in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Currently, I'm setting a variable to correspond to a circle's width and height, like so:

```
$circle-diameter: 70%;

.circle {
    width: $circle-diameter;
    height: $circle-diameter;
}
```

However, the circle's width becomes 70% of the parent element's width, and the height becomes 70% of the parent element's height, which yields an oval that is wider than it is tall. Ideally, I'd like to convert `.circle-diameter` to a fixed size and assign the circle's width and height to that fixed size. Is there a solution for this in CSS/SASS?

Comment: Well, the easiest solution is to set `$circle-diametar` in pixels, why don't you do that?

Comment: I'd like the circle-diameter to change with the size of the screen. Essentially, the circle is supposed to act as a magnifying glass for a graphic in the background, and having a fixed circle-diameter looks good on small screens but is not readable on larger screens.

Comment: If none of the other answers work the way you need them to, you could use media queries to change the `$circle-diameter`length on certain breakpoints. If you're creating responsive webpage, you will already use media queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `padding-top` instead of `height`, it will work because padding is relative to parent width.

```
.circle{
  width: 70%;
  padding-top: 70%;
  /* height: 0; */
}
```

http://codepen.io/yukulele/pen/PzGgNM

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to have a **fixed ratio** between width and height. For a circle tho, the width/height ratio is 1. There's a hacky way to accomplish that task. First I'd like to write a css class that always provides us a space that has width/height ratio of 1. To do so:

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wbe9juL/2/)

**Why this works?** Because, If you use percentage based units on padding, It always be relative to element's width. [See reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties)

Next I always like to use absolute hack to provide myself a workaround in that nicely 1/1 ratio square that we've create.

See [Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/9wbe9juL/3/)

Using position: absolute for our own good, we've created a element that has a fixed ratio and has a working width/height properties.

After It depends on what you need to do. In your case I've created a nice circle for to examine the situation.

See [Fiddle 3](https://jsfiddle.net/9wbe9juL/)

### Working source code

```
**Css**

.ratio-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
}

.im-something-has-some-width {
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid lime;
}

.space-provider {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.yay-i-have-a-square-field {
  // lets use it for our own goods!
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="im-something-has-some-width">
  <div class="ratio-1">
    <div class="space-provider">
      <div class="yay-i-have-a-square-field">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```